# Laravel 5 - Eloquent JOIN confusion

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two simple tables, cats and breeds:

```
mysql> select * from cats;
+----+--------+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name   | date_of_birth | breed_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+--------+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Rita   | 2008-07-06    |        1 | 2015-05-09 20:40:49 | 2015-05-09 20:50:20 |
|  2 | Muni   | 1992-05-15    |        3 | 2015-05-09 20:50:54 | 2015-05-09 20:50:54 |
|  3 | Hector | 2005-01-23    |        4 | 2015-05-09 21:08:23 | 2015-05-09 21:08:23 |
+----+--------+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from breeds;
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Domestic   |
|  2 | Persian    |
|  3 | Siamese    |
|  4 | Abyssinian |
+----+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

All I want to do is get a list of the cats that are of a certain breed. In the cats table, breed_id is a FK that points to the PK of the breeds table. The example code in my book which is supposed to return a view with all cats of a specific breed returns no results:

The url I am trying is /cats/breeds/Domestic

The view that is generated uses this logic in the routes.php file:

```
Route::get('cats/breeds/{name}', function($name)
{
    $cats = Furbook\Cat::with('breeds')
        ->whereName($name)
        ->get();
dd($cats);
});
```

When I dd($cats) I get zero results even though I have a cat with a domestic breed_id of 1. What have I done wrong here?

EDIT:

I can get it to work with the following hacky code, which first gets the id from the breeds table by querying against the name field, then queries the cats table with that id:

```
$breed = Furbook\Breed::whereName($name)->get();
$id = $breed[0]['attributes']['id'];
$cats = Furbook\Cat::whereId($id)->get();
```

How do I make this into one Eloquent query? I see no examples for this kind of query on the Laravel site.

For more information this is how the models look:

```
class Breed extends Model {

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function cats()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Furbook\Breed');
    }

}

class Cat extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'date_of_birth',
        'breed_id',
    ];

    public function breed()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Furbook\Breed');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking the system to give you all cats with a name of `Domestic` - not all cats of the breed name `Domestic`.

Assuming your model relationships are in order, you could do e.g.

```
$cats = Furbook\Breed::whereName($name)->first()->cats;
```

Also, my Burmese cat just hit the monitor; I think she's upset that she's not in the breeds list.

Comment: Your solution produced a sql error. I can share it if you want to see it. It was basically querying the breeds table with a field that only exists in cats, breed_id.

Comment: fyi it's "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'breeds.breed_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `breeds` where `breeds`.`breed_id` = 1 and `breeds`.`breed_id` is not null)"

Comment: Then I assume you have not set up relationships between the breeds and the cats in your models? I mean, I'm essentially doing the same thing as in your edit.

Comment: I updated my original post. FYI all the code besides my little hack is coming straight from the book 'laravel 5 essentials' (a new book with a surprising number of errors).

Comment: Great, relevant code always makes it easier. It looks like both models are referring to `Furbook\Breed`; the one in the `cats()` function should be `Furbook\Cat`. That also explains the SQL error you got above - Laravel is trying to search your breeds table for cats.

Comment: In the Breed class I changed the line to this: return $this->hasMany('Furbook\Cat'); and it finally worked. Thank you Joel. To anyone else reading this, don't buy 'Laravel 5 Essentials'. This is only one of several errors in the book.

Comment: Sucks to hear about the book being bad, but I'm glad you got it working. Hope the rest of the book is less crappy.